# What does visitFunction error mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Running Node.js@0.8.15 + Express@3.0.4 + Jade@0.27.7 + Stylus@0.31.0.
For some reason getting the following error. Does anybody know what this means?

I don't think I am doing anything weird. This is occurring when I am doing: `res.render(view, response);`

```
Property 'visitFunction' of object #<Object> is not a function
    at Object.Compiler.visitNode (/app/node_modules/jade/lib/compiler.js:176:32)
    at Object.Compiler.visit (/app/node_modules/jade/lib/compiler.js:161:10)
    at Object.Compiler.visitBlock (/app/node_modules/jade/lib/compiler.js:253:12)
    at Object.Compiler.visitNode (/app/node_modules/jade/lib/compiler.js:176:32)
    at Object.Compiler.visit (/app/node_modules/jade/lib/compiler.js:161:10)
    at Object.Compiler.compile (/app/node_modules/jade/lib/compiler.js:78:10)
    at parse (/app/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:101:23)
    at Object.exports.compile (/app/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:163:9)
    at Object.exports.render (/app/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:215:17)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/app/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:243:13)
```

Comment: It must be a bug in this version of Jade? I downgraded my Jade version to 0.25 and it works fine now. Downgraded via: `npm install jade@0.25`

Answer (score 6):

One of the reasons why you may get that error is because you added new properties (usually methods) to `Object.prototype`

Example:

```
Object.prototype.someNewMethod = function (value1, value2) {
    // ... perform some operations
    return this;
};
```

That way of adding new properties to `Object` is not recommended as stated in issue [#1033](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1033) for express project. [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) should be used with `enumerable` set to `false` instead.

Example of extending `Object` with `Object.defineProperty`

```
Object.defineProperty(
    Object.prototype, 
    'someNewMethod',
    {
        writable : false,
        // Will not show up in enumerable properties (including for-in loop).
        enumerable : false, 
        configurable : false,
        value : function (value1, value2) {
            // ... perform some operations
            return this;
        }
    }
);
```

I had exactly the same problem and using `Object.defineProperty` with `enumerable:false` to define new properties resolved the issue.

I hope that will help.

Comment: Thank you for simple and great answer. But why is this happening?